# While importing schema from a database into the HCL OneTest Data project, is there any limit on the number of tables that can be imported?

Tags: mysql, import, schema

When a user imports the schema or sample data set from the database then is there any limit on the number of the tables that a user can import?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to import any number of schemas in HCL One Test Data.